# Prime number verifier

Tags: functional-programming, primes, scala

I solved this [prime number verifier problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/):

```
import scala.io.StdIn

object Main extends App {
  val testCases = StdIn.readInt

  for (i <- 0 until testCases) {
    val limits = StdIn.readLine.split(" ")
    val m: Int = limits(0).toInt
    val n: Int = limits(1).toInt
    for (j <- m to n) {
      var prime = false
      if (isPrime(j))
        println(j)
    }
    println()
  }

  def isPrime(number: Int) : Boolean = {
    if (number == 1) 
      false
    else {
      for (h <- 2 to Math.sqrt(number).asInstanceOf[Int]) {
        if (number % h == 0 || number == 1) {
          return false
        }
      }
      true
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the code this way because Scala doesn't have `break` statements, and `return` statements aren't very functional either. How do I go about writing this code in a more functional and idiomatic manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
def isPrime(n:Int):Boolean = n match {
  case 1 => false
  case 2 => true
  case 3 => true
  case 5 => true
  case 7 => true
  case n if (n%2==0 || n%3==0 || n%5==0 || n%7==0) => false
  case _ => (Stream.iterate(3, Math.sqrt(n).toInt+1){_ + 2} dropWhile((x:Int) => n%x != 0)).isEmpty
}
```

The code is straightforward. We know that the prime numbers below 10 are 2, 3, 5, 7. If a given number is the multiple of 2, 3, 5, or 7, is't not a prime. In other case (the last `case` branch) it generates stream from 3 to `ceil(sqrt(n))` with step 2. We know that even numbers can't be a prime. And check that the argument is a multiple of any number in the stream. Basically the same logic with the original code. The reason I use `Stream` is to use lazy evaluation. With lazy evaluation, we can avoid unnecessary computation.

Comment: All the cases seem just premature optimization, the asker is very beginner and I fear you will only confuse him, Also I feel like generating the small divisors should be its own method.

Comment: @ntaibs, you really need to say at least *something* about the advantages of your code and what it does.

Comment: I think the stackoverflow gods want you to explain what makes this idiomatic, functional code?

Comment: Where is the documentation for Stream.iterate? I found Stream.iterator but not Stream.iterate...

Comment: 1.) The code does not compile at least on my system (Java8, Scala 2.11.7) 2.) Shouldn't it be `.toInt` instead of `.asInstanceOf[Int]` which is like a type cast?

Comment: I updated the code. It worked well in the previous Scala (I don't remember the version), however, it doesn't compile now. And yes, `.toInt` looks better.

Comment: `Stream.iterate` is documented on Stream's companion object. It is a method on the companion object, not on the class.